# How to use conditional formatting in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I am trying to make a spreadsheet black out non-needed information for individuals that meet a certain criteria. Their criteria is in column `A` and I need it to void cells `B10:15` through `C10:15` and cells `F10:15` through `J10:15`

To sum up: if cell `A10` is less than or equal to X then color in black cells `B10:15` through `C10:15` and cells `F10:15` through `J10:15`.

Answer (score 2):

select cell to format then [Conditional Formatting] [New rule...] "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

```
=$A$10<=X
```

where X is the value, then click [Format..] and choose the color to fill.

verify that there is no quotes, for example this will not work

```
="$A$10<X"
```